# Redirect to dashboard if user is logged in with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am trying to make my app direct to the dashboard on initial load if the user has authenticated with Firebase already.

Basically, if the user has logged in. I want them to see the dashboard instead of the login page when they open the app on their phone.

I've tried to place this in my `app.run()`. It works and does what I want but it results in an ugly error

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

This runs about 20 times before stopping.

My code in the `app.run()` function:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  if($rootScope.user)
  {
    if(next.name === 'login')
  {
    $state.go('tab.dash');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('Do Nothing, User Is Not Logged In');
  }
}
});
```

How do I do this without getting any errors?

Comment: get your code indentation right. its hard to read. and might that also be an issue? your `else{...}` belongs to `if(next.name === 'login')`. this might not be what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your code within $ionicPlatform.ready (without $stateChangeStart).

I'm using Parse for my app but here is my code.

```
.run(function($state, $ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
      $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;

      if (currentUser) {
          $state.go('tab.home');
          $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
      } else {
          $state.go('login');
      } 

  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this on https://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/

```js
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
      var $state = $injector.get("$state");
      var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
      if ($rootScope.user) {
        $state.go("app.dashboard");
      } else {
        $state.go("app.login");
      }
});
```

That should solve your problem